# MySQL combine columns of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables like indicated below:
Table1:

```
name    surname    age
----    -------    ---
 a         b       null
 c         d       null
```

Table 2:

```
age
---
 1 
 4
```

I want to combine them into first table (Table1) like

```
name    surname    age
----    -------    ---
 a         b        1
 c         d        4
```

(they have the same number of rows) How can I combine them?

Comment: uhmm what is their relationship?

Comment: How are you connecting the users in `Table 1` with the age in `Table 2`? Or are you trying to do by row number?

Comment: The relation is their row numbers.

Comment: @JoshuaJeanThree bad design, you should recreate it by giving primary keys.

Comment: I know it is bad. But it was given to me in a dataset.

Comment: It may be a bad design, but there is at least one useful case like this - where you have a bunch of unique tokens in one table, and want to add them to another table.  The order is irrelevant, so a key is irrelevant.  And thus the solution is relevant, so thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe you want this,

```
SELECT a.Name, a.SurName, b.Age
FROM
  (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 RankNo,
           Name, Surname
    FROM   Table1, (SELECT @row := 0) r
  ) a
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT @row1 := @row1 + 1 RankNo,
           Age
    FROM   Table2, (SELECT @row1 := 0) r
  ) b ON a.RankNo = b.RankNo
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c2a9/5)

Comment: how can we be sure that rows will always be returned in the same order? theoretically mysql could return rows with any order, unless you specify an order by

Comment: @fthiella *mysql could return rows with any order*. nope. it depends on which field you have set an index first.

Comment: without knowing if there's an index or not, rows order can't be determined. But I am also not sure that an index would solve this problem, of course MySql would use an index to return rows and to sort rows, but I am not sure if that's guaranteed or documented somewhere.

Comment: pls see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html it looks like that, when no explicit index is given, default fifo order is always guaranteed for InnoDB tables. So your answer should be correct!